# Implicit declaration of function '_objc_rootRetainCount' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, xcode7

XCode returns to me a warning while declaring the method below saying that "Implicit declaration of function '_objc_rootRetainCount' is invalid in C99", so what is the problem?

`id  __strong obj = [[NSObject alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"count: %d",_objc_rootRetainCount(obj));`

Comment: You've forgotten to include a header file.  `objc-internal.h` maybe.

Comment: @trojanfoe should I import the runtime framework?

Comment: @trojanfoe thx,pretty guy。

Comment: So, what exactly did you miss? There's no `#import "objc-internal.h"`. Or did I miss something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Calios

No more `#import "objc-internal.h"` at 2021-11-23,
so you need to declare it by yourself.

Demo:

```
@import Foundation;

// no more #import "objc-internal.h" at 2021-11-23
// so you need to declared it by yourself.
extern uintptr_t _objc_rootRetainCount(id obj);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    NSObject *tmp = nil;
    {
        NSObject *obj111 = [[NSString alloc] init];  // 1
        //p1112 = (__bridge_retained CFTypeRef) obj111;
        CFTypeRef p1112 = (__bridge CFTypeRef) obj111;
        tmp = obj111;
        NSLog(@"--->  CFGetRetainCount(cfMA) = %d, %d", (int) CFGetRetainCount(p1112), _objc_rootRetainCount(obj111));
        id obj = (__bridge_transfer id) p1112;
        //[obj retain];  // 2
        //[p1112 release]; // 1
        NSLog(@"--->  CFGetRetainCount(cfMA) = %d", (int) CFGetRetainCount(p1112));
        // [obj release]; // 0
        // [obj111 release]; // -1
    }
    //NSLog(@"---222>  CFGetRetainCount(cfMA) = %d", (int) CFGetRetainCount(p1112));
    return 0;
}
```